# Switch Keyboard Input

Tags: actionscript-3, switch-statement, flashdevelop

Tracing "moveState" shows that the variable is always in the default option of the switch, even when I'm pressing A or D keys.

var keys:Array = [];

```
private function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
}

private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}
```

In the update function I have this,

```
switch (keys)
{
    case Keyboard.A:
    moveState = "LEFT";
    break;
    case Keyboard.D:
    moveState = "RIGHT";
    break;
    default:
    moveState = "STOP"; 
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It always shows the default value, because the variable keys is an array, so it can't have the value of Keyboard.A.

My suggestion: Update the moveState variable inside the keyUp and keyDown function and use the moveState inside the update function to move left or right.

```
private function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
  switch(e.keyCode){
    case Keyboard.A:
     moveState = "LEFT";
     break;
    case Keyboard.D:
     moveState = "RIGHT";
     break;
  }
}

private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
  moveState = "STOP";
}
```